# Magento 2: Database user does not have enough privileges

Tags: php, mysql, web, phpmyadmin, magento2

I am trying to install Magento 2 but I have some issues. The following image shows the message that appears when I try to **add a Database**.
[image: Database user does not have enough privileges while installing Magento 2]

I found a solution online that says to check the **my.ini file** in MySql config section and **delete skip-grant-tables**, then restart the server. After I do that I can continue to the next steps of installing magento 2 but another issue appears. I tried to refresh **phpMyAdmin** and I got the following error.

[image]

Even though I could not gain access to **phpMyAdmin** I was able to continue the installation of magento 2. As soon as I finished the installation, I tried to access the **link for the admin** but nothing appeared to the screen. As shown in the following images.

[image]

[image]

Then I thought, I am going to put back **skip-grant-tables** in the **my.ini file** and restart the server. Now I gained access to **phpMyAdmin** as shown in the following image but now I lost access in the magento 2.

[image]

[image]

Do you have any suggestions? **Thank you!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connect to mysql using:
mysql -p -u root
Then enter
CREATE USER 'dev'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON magento2.* TO 'dev'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON magento2.* TO 'dev'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

For magento installation try to use user: dev , password: password

Comment: It works with me to give the `db_user` the `ALL PRIVILEGES`, using this command

**`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON your_db.* to 'your_db_user'@'%';`**